# perl test if symbolic function name exists

Tags: perl

If I make up a subroutine name, say

```
$type = 'Circle';
$fn = 'My'.$type.'Renderer';
```

How do I test if the subroutine named in $fn is defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `PACKAGE->can($fn)`, with PACKAGE being `main` for default.
2. `defined &{$fn}`

[`can`](http://p3rl.org/UNIVERSAL) also will return you CODE reference to this function if it exists.

Comment: +1 for `PACKAGE->can($fn)` (often `main->can($fn)`). the `defined` test makes me itchy

Comment: Yes, indeed, PACKAGE->can is really what I want. I thought that defined &{$fn} would work, but messed up my simple test. This is like pair programming with Stack Overflow. Thx.

Answer (score 5):

You might be tempted to use the `can` method, but that's wrong, it can lead to false positives since it obeys inheritance. You want to use [`exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html).

```
my $name = ...;
my @args = ...;
die("$name doesn't exist\n") if !exists(&$name);
(\&$name)->(@args);
```

`$name->(@args)` would suffice without strict. The weird syntax bypasses strict.

Comment: This is assuming, of course, that checking for inheritance *isn't* wanted.

Comment: @Robert P, It's not an assumption. It's what the OP asked for ("How do I test if the **subroutine** named"). He didn't ask about methods. `exists` (or `defined`) for subs, `can` for methods.

Comment: In fact, both are interesting cases, but mine is that I have a main program, calling a subroutine in a package. In that subroutine, I need to know if I can call a given made up name that MAY be either in the main program or in some other loaded package, including mine.

Comment: @Don, Yes, I know, and `exists` works perfectly fine for that. `$name = "MyModule::some_sub";`. `can`, on the other hand, usually works, but can give the  wrong answer. (`can` uses `exists` too, but checks more than one package.)